# Adding .settings to .NET Core project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, settings.settings

Is it possible to add a .settings file to .NET Core projects in Visual Studio? If not, what's the equivalent/alternative way to achieve this with .NET Core?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. There is a well write documentation https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add strongly-typed values into the IOC container from the `appsettings` file:

#### appsettings.json

```
{
  // ...other stuff...
  "MyConfiguration": {
    "ValueOne": "Some value",
    "ValueTwo": "2"
  }
}
```

#### MyConfiguration.cs

```
public class MyConfiguration
{
    public string ValueOne { get; set; }

    public int ValueTwo { get; set; }
}
```

#### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<MyConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("MyConfiguration"));
}
```

You can then get them by requesting `IOptions<MyConfiguration>`, like so:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController(IOptions<MyConfiguration> config)
    {
        var someValue = config.Value.ValueOne; // "Some value"
    }
}
```